# how to make sure my django app1 url is not accessible by app2

Tags: django, web-applications

My problem is I have a app called guardian, which has login, register features.
Now there is another app called tutor, which also has the same. and when I login to guardian it automatically logs in tutor app also.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is handled for the whole Django instance, not per app.

What you probably want to do is to distinguish between different user types (tutor, guardian). The out-of-the-box way to achieve this is by using Django's built in [permission system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

You can create two `groups` - one for guardians and one for tutors. You'll also need (at least) two new permissions - `can_see_tutor_app` and `can_see_guardian_app`, for example.

You add guardians to the guardians group and tutors to the tutors group.

I assume you are using `user.is_authenticated` or similar to check if user is logged in. Add to this a check for the appropriate permissions in each app.

This is all I can suggest with the information you've provided.